# Android: remove a TextView after an animation

Tags: android, android-animation, textview

In my app I add a TextView programmatically and after I do an animation (traslate+alpha) in this way

```
TextView point = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

//... all option for the TextView

Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.move_result_point);
        anim.setAnimationListener(this);
        point.startAnimation(anim);
```

my xml animation is

```
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true">

   <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:toYDelta="-50%p"
        android:duration="700" 
        />
   <alpha 
       android:fromAlpha="1"
       android:toAlpha="0"
       android:duration="700"/>
</set>
```

The now I want to remove the TextView generated when the animation finish, I know that I can do  it in

```
@Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
}
```

but how I can recognize the exact TextView that I generated in the other method? I can generated many TextView in my layout...
can you help me?

thanks

Comment: try to assign ID for each generated Text View ??

Comment: or better: use `setTag` if it is not used for some other purposes. `point.setTag("animating"); point.startAnimation(anim);' then inside `onAnimationEnd` use `findViewByTag("animating")` -> `setVisibility` or `parent.remove(point);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
public class ViewAnimationListener implements AnimationListener {
    View view;
    public void setView(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        // Do whatever you want with your view
    }
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    }
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
    }
}
```

So when you want to animate your TextView:

```
ViewAnimationListener listener = new ViewAnimationListener();
listener.setView(point);

Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.move_result_point);
anim.setAnimationListener(listener);

point.startAnimation(anim);
```